# 2001 Honda Civic EX overheating fans not working

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

Okay so I have tried everything.

My car was overheating so I replaced the head gasket since it needed one anyways, but it is still overheating. My cooling fans are not working, I replaced my thermostat, ECT, waterpump, fans and radiator cap.

I'm a beginner mechanic and I'm so stumped. I replaced everything related to the cooling system, I even ran a jumper wire from my fan switch positive and negative and the fans turned on. I have no idea what to do next, only thing I haven't replaced is the radiator.

Comment: Do your radiator hoses feel hot? What condition and level is your coolant? Did you purge the air out of the cooling system after your repairs?

Comment: My upper gets a little warm but doesn't have pressure and my lower stayed cold my coolent I have bleed out all the air and my coolant is full to where it over flows with the car on and cap off

Comment: I think you have a flow problem. Most likely, your radiator is obstructed. Drain it and give it a good flush. There are household cleaners that dissolve rust and lime and waterscaling, you may want to buy a gallon of that stuff and fill your radiator with it and let it sit for a few hours.

Comment: Okay I was think about doing that befor I change my radiator thanks for the help it's really appreciated I'll get back to you afterwords

Comment: Have you checked your fuses and relays?

Comment: Yes I have swapped relays with others and interior and exterior fuses are good

Comment: Okay so I bought a temp gun instead first it turns out my car is not overheating acording to the gauge it was but the car was at about 160 and the gauge was at the red I ran it for about 30 min before it got to 211 without the thermostat but my fans still didn't turn on

Comment: Not sure if this will work on your vehicle, but disconnect the temperature sending unit and see if the fans turn on then. A lot of cars will automatically cut in the fans if the sending unit is disconnected or if there is a disruption in the continuity between the sensor and the PCU. This will tell you if the PCU is operating the fans (if they cut in). Doesn't discount this if they don't, though. You said you tried to change out relays, but did you try to put a jumper wire in place of the fan relay? This will let you know they are working and the power circuit is good.

Comment: The temperature sending unit is the coolant temp sensor correct?  And no I have tried the jumper wire on the relay how do you recommend I do that?

Comment: Have not tried*

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and changed tstat and still no fan would cycle on and off and yes over heat. Then I changed the thermoswitch which is next to thermostats which tells fan to come on when temp of water get high. I changed mine and it fixed the problem, fans will now cycle on and off automatically to cool radiator

Comment: Which car was this for?